# what is the low power Consumption java card

Tags: mobile, power-management, javacard

Hi I am new to java card development.so i want to build application which encrypt data coming from the Mobile device(mobile phone) as NFC technology and send back to the device.i couldn't found any related document about java card power consumption.because the reason is mobile phone have limited power.so i want to know how java cards power consumption is works?? and what is the best low power contact less java card.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Java Card is not a chip by itself, it is only an on-card runtime with a standardized API. So the power consumption is completely dependent on the implementation.

Now to comply with ISO 14443 which specifies the chip + antenna will have to conform to certain characteristics. This includes the frequency range but also power consumption. Normally the card should be readable up to about 7 cm but for weak readers the distance is normally around 5 cm. Strangely enough, some chip/antenna combinations show "holes" at different distances in  operation.

Note that the amount of energy that can be used depends a lot on the distance. In general, the closer the card the more power. Most smart cards work at higher speeds when they are able to receive more power.

Personally I like NXP because they seem to have few implementation mistakes. I also like ISO 14443 type A slightly better than type B. But this is personal preference and the landscape is changing fast. Furthermore, it is only possible to measure the performance of the combination of chip, packaging and antenna together.